# Home Router NAT Network configuration Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, iptables, router, nat

I have Ubuntu 20.04 desktop and home router and I trying to open ports to have an acces from internet.

Here is interface info

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:cb:8a:5d:85:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.178/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 5381sec preferred_lft 5381sec
    inet6 fe80::dacb:8aff:fe5d:85c6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:35:a8:08:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Netplan

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: yes
```

On Ubuntu I have opened ports with UFW

```
ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
7080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8443                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
7080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8443 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

On my router I have forwarded ports to 192.168.0.178 Ubuntu desktop [nat forward ports to virtual server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdZ0I.png)

When I was using Windows 10 and Ubuntu on VirtualBox the conection was working.

> tried to ssh 192.168.0.178 from laptop and does not work.

But ports are still closed and i cannot SSH to my Ubuntu 20.04.
Help me please :*(

Comment: Are you able to connect to these ports from inside your internal network? If no, there's some problem with settings on your machine. If yes, there's some problem with port forwarding on your router. It is also possible that your ISP is blocking those ports outside of your router - in that case you probably can't do anything about this.

Comment: @raj tried to ssh 192.168.0.178 from laptop and does not work. Maybe this problem could be because docker installation?